# How to create Google+ Plus One button while already having Leaderboards implemented using Google Play Game Services SDK for C++?

Tags: c++, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-plus-one

I'm developing an android app. It already has leaderboadrs implemented using Google Play Game Services SDK for C++
([Google Games C++ SDK Documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/GettingStartedNativeClient)) . This already handles the authorisation.

Now I want to add a Plus One button that belongs to the Google+ Platform, a part of Google Play Servives. The problem is that for there is no C++ SDK for it ( [Google+ Platform Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/) ). I can probably use Android API to do it but what to do with leaderboards that are already written using C++ SDK?

Is there any way to use leaderboards with Google Play Game Services C++ SDK and Plus One button using Google Play Services SDK for Android at the same time? Both APIs have their authorization methods for logging in Google Play Services. Or does it mean that the only solution for me is to rewrite leaderboards using the Android API instead of C++ one?

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you should be able to use the web-based share dialog by opening a URL to `https://plus.google.com/share?url=<url>`. You also should still be able to [trigger the share intent from Java code](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/), e.g.:

```
  Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```